# Controller --- Factory: passing parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router

I have this function in my controller :

```
    $scope.goToPath = function ( path, pid ) {

    $scope.pid = pid;
    console.log("scope pid : " + $scope.pid);
    $scope.edit = true;
    $state.go(path);
};
```

then i'm calling this function to get a promise from my factory :

```
$scope.getProjectById = function () {
    projectFactory.getProject($scope.pid)
        .success(function (data) {
            if(data == null){
                $scope.errorMessage = "Le projet avec l'id : " + pid + " n'existe pas";
            }else {

                $scope.project = data;
            }

        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.errorMessage = "Erreur : " + data.error + ' ' + status;
        })
};
```

And my Factory looks like this :

```
 factory.getProject = function (projectId) {
        console.log('Project Id factory : '+projectId);
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/gestionprojet/Project/' + projectId)
    };

    return factory;
```

but the variable here projectId is null, now I've checked as your see with `console.log()` and the pid in my controller has a value but in the factory it's equal to `null`.

In my view I'm calling it like :

```
ng-init="getProjectById()"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How do you calling `$scope.goToPath`?

Comment: `ng-click="goToPath('addProject', p.id)"`

Comment: So,after redirection from `goToPath ` you are calling `getProjectById `?

Comment: yep and I'm calling it with `ng-init="getProjectById()"` in the redirected view.

Comment: With this scenari,the current scope get destroyed and new scope is getting created.So,your `$scope.pid = pid;` is also getting destoyed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With this scenario,your current scope is getting destroyed and new scope is getting creates.So,`pid` assigned to scope is also getting destroyed.

You can do like this one.

In function `$scope.goToPath`,

```
 $scope.goToPath  = function(path, pid ){
   ....
   $state.go(path,{project_id:pid })

}
```

And in the target controller where your view is getting landed,

access it using `$stateParams` by injecting it.

You can refer here [angular-ui](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing) routing

Comment: And you need to add `params: {
            projectId: null
        }` in your state definition